# Needed inputs on Automic ARA

Tags: automic

We are planning to use Automic ARA for `WAR` file automated deployment. But I cannot find proper inputs about Automic ARA. Is it open source or licensed? How to implement ARA? What is the feedback when compared it with other automation tools. I got the details for the architecture and other details about ARA. I want to know a comparative study about ARA.

Answer (score 0):

Automic ARA is licensed - you can find its documentation here: https://docs.automic.com/documentation?offering_id=1436522539027

for suited action packs and plugins you can take a look at:
https://marketplace.automic.com/

basically it is a hybrid solution of workflow and model driven ARA. In contrast to uDeploy (workflow driven) and XLDeploy (model driven).

The model of application, environment and package/version is mapped onto the defined deployment workflows for all targets defined in the environment.